# How many words? Help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code, it's almost right:

```
list = []
list = input('Word: ')
while list != '':
  list = input('Word: ')
for Word in list:
  print(list)
```

But it needs - You know 3 unique word(s)! - after it.

Can someone please help me finish this code, it's driving me crazy as I've tried everything to get it out

Comment: What do you mean?Elaborate.

Comment: Thought it was plain, but what it is asking is for several words to put into the question asked, say, 3 different words and 1 word repeated equals 3 words that are different. Then it is supposed to spit out "You know ? unique words" ... in this case ? would be 3. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your explanation is still not helping.Please post an example of what you want.

Comment: How many words?
You are learning a new language, and are having a competition to see how many unique words you know in it to test your vocabulary learning.

Write a program where you can enter one word at a time, and be told how many unique words you have entered. You should not count duplicates. The program should stop asking for more words when you enter a blank line.

For example:


Word: Chat
Word: Chien
Word: Chat
Word: Escargot
Word: 
You know 3 unique word(s)!
​
and


Word: Katze
Word: Hund
Word: Maus
Word: Papagei
Word: Schlange
Word: 
You know 5 unique word(s)!
​

Comment: Hope this helps as I can't put much more down.

Comment: It nearly works but won't put down the last part wanted, that is the bit that prints out the result "You know ? unique word(s)!" ... the ? being how many unique words are given in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count=0 
//increments when a unique word is entered.
var1=""
i=0
list=[]
var1=input('Word: ')
while(var1!="" && var1!=" "):
 //stops when the input is space or null
               if var1 not in list 
//checks if the word is already present
                   list[i]=var1
                   i=i+1
                   count=count+1
                   var1=input('Word: ')
print("Printing your unique words")
i=0
while(i<count) // prints unique words
        print(list[i] "\n")
        i=i+1

Print("No. of unique words entered"+count)
//prints no. of unique words
```

This will do exactly what you want.Let me know in a comment if some error occurs.The program will stop taking input when the user enters space or nothing.

Comment: None of it works Mathews, I do appreciate your help, but when I put it in the Python 3 terminal it comes back as indents wrong, print(list[i] "\n") is invalid syntax etc. etc. Sorry, have tried to correct it all but none comes back to work anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is for those of you who are using Python 3, and this is what I did when I did the *Grok Learning - Introduction to Programming (Python)* course.

```
words = []
word = input('Word: ')
while word != '':
    if word not in words:
        words.append(word)
        word = input('Word: ')
print('You know', len(words), 'unique word(s)!')
```

Hope it helps anyone out there in the future.